# How to show an image in ImageView in Netbeans?

Tags: java, mysql, image, netbeans, imageview

I have a list of movies and information about them that's saved in a mysql database. When I click on a movie on the list, it shows me information about the movie, but I have trouble loading the image for each movie. One of the columns in the database is "ImageName". All images are saved in the same folder, so I'm trying to load them like this:

```
@FXML
ImageView sl;
...
String imgName = this.film.getImageName();
i = new Image("/movies/images/" + imgName); 
sl.setImage(i)
```

It doesn't work, but when I try to load a specific image like this, it works:

```
i = new Image("/movies/images/Lotr.jpg");
```

I have tried printing the path to the image to see what the problem is:

```
String msg = ("/movies/images/" + imgName);
System.out.print(msg);
```

Result: `/movies/images/   L   o   t   r`

It prints three spaces between the letters of image name, so I'm assuming that's why my code isn't working, but I don't know how to fix this.

Edit:
Here's how I choose an image and assign the name to imageName:

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
fileChooser.setTitle("Select Image File");
fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll( new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Image Files",
                        "*.bmp", "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.gif")); 
File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
filePath = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

File destinationFile = new File("C:\\Users\\t\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Movies\\src\\movies\\images\\" + sourceFile.getName());
imageName = sourceFile.getName();
copyFile(sourceFile, destinationFile);
```

Btw, the names of images look correct in the database.

Comment: Show us the code where `imgName` gets assigned...

Comment: I edited the post, do I need to add more code?

Comment: Those "spaces" seem to me like results of some mis-conversion of character encodings.Check your database connection for charset encoding..

Comment: I changed the collation and now it works. Thank you!